# How can it taken the specific args in lists of list?

Tags: python

for example we have;

```
L = [["Ak","154"],["Bm","200"],["Ck","250"], ["Ad","500"],["Ac","600"]]
```

I want to choose first element starting with 'A' I want to find their values which are in second element; see this output should like

```
["154","500","600"] or like [["154"],["500"],["600"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Filter and map with a list comprehension:

```py
[b for a, b in L if a[0] == "A"]
```

Or, if you need to search for prefixes of more than one character:

```py
[b for a, b in L if a.startswith("A")]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another Solution Using `map()` and `filter()` functions**

```
L = [["Ak","154"],["Bm","200"],["Ck","250"], ["Ad","500"],["Ac","600"]]

k = list(map(lambda y:y[1], list(filter(lambda x: x[0][0] == 'A' , L))))
```

Output:

```
['154', '500', '600']
```